# typeahead:closed will be triggered when losing focus

Tags: typeahead.js

From documentations:

> `typeahead:closed` – Triggered when the dropdown menu of a typeahead is
>   closed.

But when adding `typeahead:closed` to typeahead, it will get triggered also `onblur`.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69b7hhv0/2/), i have

```
.on("typeahead:closed",function() {
     alert("Dropdown Closed!"); 
});
```

The alert will be triggered when the dropdown is closed and also when losing focus, click in and click out of the textbox you'll see the alert.

Is this a bug? is there any way it should only be triggered when the dropdown menu is closed and not each time i'm clicking in and out?

Comment: It is at least consistent, i.e, typeahead:opened also triggers on focus.

Comment: But i need to perform something only when the dropdown is actually closed, not when losing focus, is there any alternative to that?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Ever find a solution?

Comment: Not really, but something... take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/dhpebjxc/

Comment: Its not working good with all versions i think.